# Plotlyjs ticktext/tickvals not showing xaxis labels

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have been trying to utilize the tickvals/ticktext on plotlyjs to be able to show duplicate values on a graph for the xaxis. It works in the aspect of separating the data (having multiple duplicate values be on the xaxis, but a 1:1 data point) -- the issue that I am having is that no xaxis tick marks or xaxis labels show up for the ticks.

Here is a code pen of my problem:
https://codepen.io/hiquetj/pen/yLeBNjJ

Here is the code for easier reading:

```
var trace1 = {
  y: [1323,1070,849,1312,1214,1264,680,2006,1625,0,1199,1770,1880,708,603,649,1384,732,2312,92,1377,1125,1219,1757,1207,2397,1190,1818,2846,1200,1685,1563,1203,1059,820,4303,812,3640,1924,4185,1269,2263,1140,1210,1638,1362,4915,1594,683,1222],
  mode: 'markers'
};

var trace2 = {
  y: [5870,1574,1372,2093,1361,1388,615,1927,947,,1040,,,638,546,542,1051,637,4161,289,1103,0,1308,1658,1340,2198,1245,1568,2392,1297,1583,1281,1282,697,482,3633,653,3233,2096,3815,1401,2116,867,1232,1420,1010,4091,478,208,1262],
  mode: 'lines'
};

var trace3 = {
  y: [1141,1324,424,668,414,407,494,1763,1100,,522,360,108,474,145,621,689,234,154,40,303,364,407,1133,347,1527,358,1745,1223,345,1131,1024,365,754,614,1894,287,5332,363,568,335,1545,1294,383,1255,1107,2090,612,66,390],
  mode: 'lines+markers'
};

var data = [ trace1, trace2, trace3 ];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    ticktext: [24346247,24346247,24346247,24346247,24332892,24332892,24332892,24332670,24332670,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24316962,24316962,24316962,24290013,24290013,24290013,24290013,24290013,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933],
    tickvals: [24346247,24346247,24346247,24346247,24332892,24332892,24332892,24332670,24332670,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24330025,24316962,24316962,24316962,24290013,24290013,24290013,24290013,24290013,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933,23738933],
  },
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

[image: X Axis labels not showing up but y axis is]

Example of x axis labels not showing up through codepen.

Comment: Your traces do not have any x values. Implicitly, they are assigned x values from 1 to n, which is why your ticktexts will only visible if your tickval array is `[1, 2, 3, ..., n]`.

Comment: @mit via this issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1516 - this is how we get duplicate x values to work. Unfortunately, if I set an x value like you said - it will not take duplicate values and give me a scrappy graph of only 4 xvalues

Comment: I did not tell you to set an x value. I said that if you wanted your solution to work, you would have to change your tickval array, like so https://jsfiddle.net/9okdx4b2/

Comment: @mit ahhhh I see what you mean. Let me try that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @mit this worked, thank you. Mind making an answer to this question so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it worked for you, answer coming right up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not set x values for your traces, they are automatically assigned x values from 0 to n. Your ticktexts will therefore only be visible if your tickval array is `[0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n]`, see this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9okdx4b2/